# Should the [standalone] tag be burninated?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I've seen a bunch of questions tagged [xulrunner](/questions/tagged/xulrunner) and [standalone](/questions/tagged/standalone) lately. Now a XULRunner application (as opposed to a Firefox extension) is always standalone so the second tag adds no value. Looking through the other questions with the [standalone](/questions/tagged/standalone) tag (currently 196 of them) - this tag is apparently used to describe something that is only meaningful in the context of a particular framework/application, IMHO it is a meta-tag. E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719933/hadoop-namenode-gets-corrupted-while-writing-to-hadoop-cluster-through-a-batch-j):

> We have a hadoop 0.22.0 instance running in our hadoop cluster. It is running in standalone mode.

Without knowing anything about hadoop, if the "standalone mode" part is actually important then this question should use a tag like [hadoop-standalone](/questions/tagged/hadoop-standalone) rather than the meaningless [standalone](/questions/tagged/standalone). Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632614/using-spring-in-a-stand-alone-jar-for-dependency-injectection):

> I'm responsible for a stand alone java project(used as a jar by a server)

Again, if this distinction were important, a tag like [java-standalone-webapp](/questions/tagged/java-standalone-webapp) would be more appropriate. But I don't think that it is important.

It's similar with the other questions. Should this tag be burninated or is there a reason to have it?

[standalone](/questions/tagged/standalone) **× 282**

Various Uses:

- standalone operator ([Operator overloading function in class c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687779/operator-overloading-function-in-class-c))
- standalone server: ([Python stand-alone HTTP server with script running support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901757/python-stand-alone-http-server-with-script-running-support))
- standalone web app ([Is there anyway to make a standalone chrome web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295663/is-there-anyway-to-make-a-standalone-chrome-web-app))
- standalone app ([Java: Graphic framework for standalone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761903/java-graphic-framework-for-standalone-application))
- standalone plugin ([Where to get and how to use zend_pdf standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717024/where-to-get-and-how-to-use-zend-pdf-standalone))
- standalone process (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593218/batch-container-vs-standalone-jobs)

Comment: So, what you're asking here is **can the [standalone] tag standalone?** :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [standalone](/questions/tagged/standalone) tag has been eliminated.

Comment: That's like almost a year old post. This post should have been dig deep enough ;)

Comment: @mtk I asked the same question a couple weeks ago and it got marked a duplicate of this one.