# Burn: [standalone]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

This has dozens of different meanings and cannot be used by itself (stand alone... hehe).

[standalone](/questions/tagged/standalone) **× 282**

Various Uses:

- standalone operator ([Operator overloading function in class c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687779/operator-overloading-function-in-class-c))
- standalone server: ([Python stand-alone HTTP server with script running support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901757/python-stand-alone-http-server-with-script-running-support))
- standalone web app ([Is there anyway to make a standalone chrome web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295663/is-there-anyway-to-make-a-standalone-chrome-web-app))
- standalone app ([Java: Graphic framework for standalone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761903/java-graphic-framework-for-standalone-application))
- standalone plugin ([Where to get and how to use zend_pdf standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717024/where-to-get-and-how-to-use-zend-pdf-standalone))
- standalone process (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593218/batch-container-vs-standalone-jobs)

Comment: dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133471/should-the-standalone-tag-be-burninated